DatepickerModule is not compatible with ivy angular 17 - ng2-datepicker v12.0.0
I installed Angular 17.3.9 after running npm start command. The DatepickerModule started throwing an error.
app.component.module.ts:
import { DatepickerModule } from 'ng2-datepicker';
...
...

@NgModule({
    imports: [DatepickerModule]
})


Error: src/app/app.module.ts:16:5 - error NG6002: **'DatepickerModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.
DatepickerModule
node_modules/ng2-datepicker/lib/datepicker.module.d.ts:3:22
3 export declare class DatepickerModule {
This likely means that the library (ng2-datepicker) which declares DatepickerModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

Please help me.
I tried cleaning the project, deleted node_module folder and reinstalled all packages 3 times. I am expecting ng2-datepicker should work with Angular v17.3.9. It is working fine with Angular v15.
